# Distribute prizes between entrants dynamically

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

This is really blowing my mind.  I have created a league where I have defined prizes based on min and max positions from the number of entrants in a leauge i.e:

```
LeagueSizeID    LeagueSizeMin    LeagueSizeMax
     1                1               24
     2                25              49
     3                500             999
```

This relates to a table which defines the payout per league, this is example for leaguesizeid 3

```
    LeaguesizeID    PositionMin PositionMax WinPerc
       3                  1         1        22.00
       3                  2         2        10.00
       3                  3         3         7.00
       3                  4         4         6.00
       3                  5         5         5.00
       3                  6         6         4.00
       3                  7         7         3.50
       3                  8         8         3.00
       3                  9         9         2.50
       3                  10        10        2.00
       3                  11        20        1.00
       3                  21        30        0.50
```

The approach I have taken is to loop each position and get the entrants which match that position.  The issue I have is that there can be joint winners.  IF there are joint winners then the second place prize needs to account.  So for the below result:

```
UserID    Position    Prize
  1          1         22.0%
  2          2         10
  3          3         6.5   // joint here so takes position 3 and 4 
  4          3         6.5   // and splits prize
  5          4         5 % // this is now position 5
```

I am using DenseRank() is SQL to order the positions but maybe I need to change this to Rank() unless anyone can point me in the right direction of an algorithm to do this driven from database objects?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your  desired results have something called `UserId`, which is not mentioned in the sample data.  You should clarify your question *and* add the sample code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look to create two intermediate result sets. Firstly `rank_bounds`. This has the UserID, rank and number of ties at that rank. The second is `exploded_payout`. This has a row for each payout position, instead of rolled up into min and max positions. Once you have this you can fairly easily get the payout percentages.

I've put it all together using common table expressions (and simplified and filled in some missing table details):

```sql
with ranks as (
  select
    UserID,
    rank() over (order by Score desc) rk
  from
    UserGameScores
  where
    GameID = 1
), rank_bounds as (
  select
    UserID,
    rk Position,
    count(1) over (partition by rk) as TieCount
  from
    ranks
), n as (
  select
    row_number() over (order by number) rn
  from
    -- if you have lots of payout lines, you might need more numbers than this
    master..spt_values
), exploded_payout as (
  select
    n.rn as Position,
    p.WinPerc
  from
    Payout p
      inner join
    n
      on p.PositionMin <= n.rn and p.PositionMax >= n.rn
) select
  UserId,
  avg(winperc)
from
  exploded_payout xp
    inner join
  rank_bounds rb
    on xp.Position >= rb.Position and
       xp.Position < rb.Position + rb.TieCount
group by
  UserId;
```

If you want the rank in the result set, you'll need to put the last bit into a CTE and join onto the ranks table again.

Although the SQL is somewhat tricky to understand. I'm not sure a procedural approach would be much simpler. Also, the SQL has the nice property that it would be fairly easy to expand to all games at once :)

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e970/9)